# How to sum the multiple Long Digit(Which has the comma) Values, What is the Standard Way,

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

How to calculate multiple numbers or long digit number, long digit conmanly have comma.

Is any standrad way to calculate this kind of numbers in PHP?

Because comma separated value cannot give the numeric value.

**Example:**

```
270,529.00 + 270,529.00
```

Comment: Write a short function to remove the commas from the string before doing the maths with it? Or store the numbers without the formatting, and only format them when you display them?

Comment: Where are your "Long Digits" coming from?

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your kind response,  some of the values which comes from web page, some of the values needs to calculate after submiting the form.